# Multiple <a> tags with different css attributes?

Tags: css

I am working on a project and a minor problem is bugging me.  I created a special button for a registration link, which in retrospect isn't needed.  So I fixed one problem but I am trying to figure out why it wasn't working before.

My special button was given this coding -

```
<div class="registerbut"><a href="pages/register.html" name="register">Register</a></div>
```

with this CSS -

```
.registerbut {
    height: 67%;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-left: 6px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: gray;
}

.registerbut a:visited,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Yeah I fashioned a button out of an `<a>` tag, which I made to look like another button it is next to, but was completely unnecessary because all I had to do was put it inside the form as a basic button.

Later on I was messing with another `<a>` tag and trying to give it specific a specific class -

```
<div class="post_link"><a href="reply.html">Example post</a></div>
```

and CSS with these attributes -

```
.post_link a:visited,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2A75B3;
}
```

but according to my element inspector, it's taking in the .registerbut CSS rather than the CSS I gave it.

Why wouldn't my new `<div>` class be overriding the other CSS?

Comment: Is the `.post_link` rule declared  after the `.registerbut` one?

Comment: `a:link, a:hover, a:active` part will be overridden by second style declaration because whatever comes last will take effect in CSS. So what are u intend to do?

Comment: I was trying to make them have different colors, and did not know that the ```a:link, hover and active``` would have effect outside of the div they were in.  And yes ```.post_link``` was after ```.registerbut```.  And actually, the first overrode the second.